# Server Explorer window does not display in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I have Visual Studio 2008 Professional and when I click on menu View -> Server Explorer, the Server explorer window does not display. Same happens when using keyboard shortcut: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

**I have tried the following:**

- Cmd -> devenv /resetsettings
- Tools > Import and Export Settings > 'Reset all settings'
- Window > Reset Window Layout
- Deleted DefaultView.SEView from %appdata%\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ServerExplorer as per [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=335494) KB article.

**Details of the environment**

- Visual Studio Professional Edition
- Version: 9.0.30729.1 SP1
- Akhsvn,
- GhostDoc
- Resharper 4.5
- Testdriven .Net

Has anyone experienced the same issue? I don't want to reinstall VS and all plugins.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to the issue was the following:

Open Visual Studio Command Prompt and type the command below

### `C:\...\>devenv /setup`

I don't know what caused the issue, and once in a while the Server Explorer disappears and I find myself having to run devenv /setup again.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the menu item Window > Reset Window Layout?  I've gotten my windows garbled before, and this sometimes fixes them.